# Moq Func<T,TResult> delegate and setting values

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I want to mock the `callback` parameter of the following method:

```
Task ExecuteReadOnlyThreadSafe(Func<IUnitOfWork, Task> callback);
```

The call of the upper method in the method that will be tested looks like this:

```
await _dbContext.ExecuteReadOnlyThreadSafe(async uow =>
{
   mobileDevices = (await uow.PushNotificationDeviceRepository.FindByUser(userId)).ToList();
});
```

And I want to set `mobileDevices` parameter to some value.

I've done the following mock:

```cs
User testUser = new User()
{
    ID = 1
};
    
IEnumerable<PushNotificationDevice> testMobileDevices = new List<PushNotificationDevice>()
{
    new PushNotificationDevice()
    {
        ID = 1,
        RegistrationID = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
        NotificationPlatform = Shared.HelperMethods.Enums.NotificationPlatformTypes.Apns,
        User = testUser
    }
};


Mock<IDbContext> mockDbContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
Mock<IUnitOfWork> mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
Mock<IPushNotificationDeviceRepository> mockPushNotificationDeviceRepository = new Mock<IPushNotificationDeviceRepository>();

mockPushNotificationDeviceRepository
    .Setup(x => x.FindByUser(It.IsAny<User>()))
    .Returns(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(testMobileDevices));

mockUnitOfWork
    .SetupGet(x => x.PushNotificationDeviceRepository)
    .Returns(mockPushNotificationDeviceRepository.Object);

mockDbContext.SetupProperty(x => x.CurrentUnitOfWork, mockUnitOfWork.Object);

var mockCallback = new Mock<Func<IUnitOfWork, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>();
    
mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.ExecuteReadOnlyThreadSafe(It.IsAny<Func<IUnitOfWork,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>()));
```

I got stuck on the mocking of ExecuteReadOnlyThreadSafe. How do I mock callback so that test will execute the content of the actual implementation:

```
await _dbContext.ExecuteReadOnlyThreadSafe(async uow =>
{
mobileDevices = (await uow.PushNotificationDeviceRepository.FindByUser(userId)).ToList();
});
```

Comment: The last metod should be:

mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.ExecuteReadOnlyThreadSafe(It.IsAny<Func<IUnitOfWork,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>(),null)));

And ignore the error: an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

I just want to set the value.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] that in :)